# Is there a way to alt-tab without the switcher interface appearing on screen?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, multiple-instances

Sometimes I like to rapidly alt-tab between two programs in order to verify that something appears identically in both. For example, at the moment I have two P4Merge windows open each displaying on-disk changes to a file; the two files are ones that must be kept in sync. (They are not identical files, but changes to them must correspond.)

So I give first one program focus, then the other, and then I repeatedly alt-tab between them so as to satisfy myself visually that I see the same thing in both places. But every time I alt-tab, an enormous black box (the alt-tab switcher interface) covers part of the screen. This is distracting, and detrimental to the visual check I'm trying to perform. If only the interface didn't appear, alt-tabbing would be an ideal tool for the check I want to make.

I would like to be able to alt-tab without anything appearing over the application displayed on-screen. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: AFAIK you can only go back to the old fashioned Windows XP style box, or the current interface. I don't believe there's a way to disable it completely. What about an alternative solution, such as showing the 2 files side-by-side, or on different monitors?

Comment: Showing the two files side-by-side or on different monitors is no good. The whole point is that they should alternately occupy the same screen space, ideally pixel-for-pixel, as I flip between the two programs. That way if I know the program instance displayed is different, but I don't see any difference on screen, I know the two are synchronised.

Comment: Okay, fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that what I want can be achieved by moving one instance of the app to a virtual desktop.

- Create a virtual desktop with Windows Key + Ctrl + D
- Open Task View using Windows Key + Tab
- Right-click one of the app instances and "move to" the new virtual desktop (probably called Desktop 2)

Now Windows Key + Control + left/right arrow flips between the desktops. And it doesn't pop anything up on screen.